# An error occurred when the project referenced seata

Tags: java, exception

The following error occurred when the project started:

> 2023-03-09 15:25:36.979  WARN 16788 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'globalTransactionScanner' defined in class
> path resource
> [io/seata/spring/boot/autoconfigure/SeataAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [io.seata.spring.annotation.GlobalTransactionScanner]:
> Factory method 'globalTransactionScanner' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty([Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
> 2023-03-09 15:25:36.996 ERROR 16788 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
io.seata.spring.annotation.scannercheckers.PackageScannerChecker.addScannablePackages(PackageScannerChecker.java:48)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty([Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

The method's class, org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/D:/respository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar!/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/D:/respository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils

I've tried many ways but can't solve it，help!

somebody can telle me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The library version of apache commons lang is too old and doesn't contain that function.

How I found out:

First you have to analyze the function signature:

`org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty([Ljava/lang/Object;)Z`

- `org.apache.commons.lang` - this is the package
- `ArrayUtils` - this is the classname where the method is located
- `isNotEmpty` - the method name inside the class
- `(...)` the parameters. `...` will be a list of further class or primitive types, but in a special form with letters, see below.
- `Z` the return type of the method. Letters explained below.

What the letters mean: The type names for parameters and return value are taken from the method `java.lang.Class.getName()`. You can read it's [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) to see the details, here in brief for your case:

- `[` is for one level of Array (multiple nested arrays will have several `[` concatenated)
- `L<classname>;` is for an object with the type of `<classname>` - for your case its the base class `java.lang.Object`.
- `Z` is for primitive `boolean`

With that information you find that the missing method is `boolean org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(java.lang.Object[])`.

Next step is to find javadocs and hope there is a version information given there, so you can search the internet for that method signature. It lead me to the [JavaDocs for Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#isNotEmpty(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))

In there, find your way to the method you searched (I linked it already), and you hopefully will find information like

> **Since:** 2.5

This means, the method you are using in your code is not contained in the library version you are using at runtime. Your code was compiled with a more recent version of the library, otherwise the compiler would have complained.

How this can happen can have multiple reasons, you could have taken a JAR file "off the shelf", that didn't specify it's dependencies properly, or you ignored that specs, etc.

Declaring a dependency of your own project to the right version of the library would be a fairly easy, but probably also is kind of a workaround, depending on your build system.

Comment: i've solved this problem by adding a version description of this package,thanks anyway~